# User input and fgets

Tags: c, fgets

I have to accept user input and write it to a file, for which I'm using `fgets()` with the idea to prevent overflows:

```
while (fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
    fputs(line, file);
```

The problem with this is that the user has to enter CTRL+Z on an empty line and then submit it to exit the input, and this might look a bit confusing. Is there a simpler way of exiting the `fgets()` input ?

What about other methods ? If I read symbol by symbol I can implement an exit character, but the user can't delete the input and this is also confusing, so I have to implement a deletion algorithm, which adds a bit too much complexity to the code.

Edit:
The user has to be able to enter C code in the terminal with as little restrictions as possible.

Comment: Works like a char on Linux. Maybe you have some strange IDE or OS? And `fgets` does not allow editing. `stdin` is a character stream!

Comment: The idea is to be able to exit the input very easily (a specific exit character probably) and I can't do that with fgets.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use the input value itself to implement a check? That way, you won't be needing any *special* implementation to mark the end of input.

To elaborate, in case you want to use an empty line to mark the end of input, you can check for the first element of the input buffer to be equal to the newline to implement the `break` condition, like

```
    while (fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
    {
            if (line[0] == '\n')
            {
                    printf("end\n");
                    break;
            }
               fputs(line, file);
    }
```

Edit: If you want to implement your own end-of-input marker, you can use that particular marker to compare against the first element (or, if it is a multi-letter marker, maybe `strcmp()` with the input) to implement the `break`.

Comment: This doesn't allow an empty line and the user might want to have an empty line.

Comment: @user3604097 I did not notice that as a part of your requirement.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but the general idea is for the user to be able to enter C code in the terminal window.

Comment: @user3604097 check the updated answer. Hope you got the idea to adjust the logic to your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I could tell the user to write "exit" and then do a strcmp on it. It's still a bit too complex but I guess that's the only way with fgets ?

Comment: Why not add a boolean variable that indicates if a newline has been inserted, and if two consecutive new line has been inserted it'll exit.

Unless the user can input as many new lines as he wants?

Comment: They have to be able to enter C programs with as little restrictions as possible.

Comment: Suspect no valid C program can have a line that begins with a `$` (except in a comment), maybe use that to exit the `while` loop?